# how does rails cache my pages in spite of perform_caching being false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

as you now, in development mode the "perform_caching" configuration in action_controller is set to false by default. this configuration is in `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

i tried a bunch of difference views(both html and json) and after a refresh, the requests were all 304(cached). so what is perform_caching doing here exactly?
by the way, i didn't use any caching method such as (cache , stale , cache_page , cache_action , ...) and maybe this is why perform_caching is not working. so how is this caching implemented?

Comment: browser caching? Not enough info to say.

Comment: Are you using any caching gem? Because by default caching is disable in development and test environment. See the link http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html